# Correct test to verify that data stems from a (given) non-stationary categorical time-series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I have a categorical random variable that can take one of 3 values (red, blue, green). The variable is called `Guess` and - over the course of a time-continuous episode - its probability distribution changes. In other words, I have a non-stationary, categorical time series.

I have a *theoretical model* that, given the current time, predicts the probability distribution of `Guess`. I also have observations of this random variable at four points during the episode (25%, 50%, 75%, 100%). One example episode could be: `blue, green, blue, blue`. I have repeated the process of measuring an episode a few times and now I have collected about 360 sequences of measurements.

I would like to test the correctness of the theoretical mode. That is, assuming the theoretical model is true, I would like to run a test (based on the data I have) to check the likelihood of observing the given set of sequences, and then either confirm or reject its efficacy. Which test should I use to test this?

---

**Edit**:

[image]

Here is a visual representation of the odds predicted by the theoretical model. Time runs along the x-axis from 0 to 1 (0% to 100%), at which point the episode completes and everything resets.

On each marker (M1 - M4) I make an observation/measurement, aka. for a single point in time I get a single measurement, e.g. green. For a full episode, I obtain 4 (repeated) measurements, e.g. (red, red, blue, green). The observations I have come from the true system (distribution?). I am curious now if the model that I have is a fitting/good description of the odds of the true system.

The background of this problem is that I have a robot that goes about its business (progression of an episode) and eventually reaches one of three goals (red, blue, green). Afterward, I can reset the robot, so I can repeat this many times. There is also a human observer watching the robot, and I want to know at which goal the human thinks the robot will end up. This belief depends on what the robot does, and likely changes as time goes on.

Related work has proposed a theoretical model for the human's belief, but it falls from the sky. There is mild evidence that it could work, but those tests were done in a slightly different domain. In essence, I don't know the extent to which I should/can rely on this model, so I want to test it instead.

What I am doing now is that I am stopping the robot at specified times (25%, 50%, 75%, 100%) and I am asking the human/observer to guess which goal the robot will end up at. This gives me a sequence of 4 measurements for each episode.

Comment: Little confused -- you have a nonstationary distribution you want to apply a test that assumes stationarity? No matter, how do measure success? If the model predicts (blue,red,blue,blue) for time t, and the measured data is (green,red,blue,blue), would you say success=(0), or success=(0,1,1,1)?

Comment: @blackeneth I don't think so; my question is exactly what kind of test I should use. I have a nonstationary distribution, some observations from that distribution (my data), and a theoretical model of the distribution. I'm trying to estimate the model's goodness of fit test, but I've never done it for this kind of data, so I am a little lost.

Comment: We need to know what you mean by "fit". How do you evaluate if a prediction fit or not? See question on "success" above.

Comment: @blackeneth I think I didn't explain my notion of time clearly enough before. At a given point `t` there is only one observation, e.g., red, not 4. I've updated my question. Does this explain it better?